# Proper escript for Hello World in erlang?

Tags: erlang

So I know that the basic Hello World Program (as in the one to output a string not the one designed for Erlang learning with spawn and other stuff) is as follows

```
-module(hello).
-export([start/0]).

start() ->
  io:format("Hello, World!").
```

Then I run erl

```
>erl
```

type

```
>c(hello)
```

and then

```
>hello
```

For the escript version would it be this ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript
-export([main/1]).

main([]) -> io:format("Hello, World!~n").
```

Then

```
chmod u+x hello
```

Where hello is the filename ?

Why can I not use the same format as the module ? (main/0 and main()) ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is just the way the escript system works. Your escript must contain a function `main/1` for the runtime to call. The escript needs a way to pass command line arguments to your function, and it does this as a list of strings, hence the need for your `main` function to take one argument.

When you build a module and run it manually from the shell, a similar requirement applies - your module must export the function you want to call (`start/0` in your example).

In fact, your example is incorrect. You create and compile the module but never call it. Evaluating

```
 hello.
```

In the shell simply repeats the atom value `hello`. To actually call your hello world function you would need to evaluate:

```
hello:start().
```